# How to set a different header color depending of the page path with @reach-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reach-router

I have a layout with a header component where all my pages are rendering as a children, so Im getting some troubles adding specific styles to the header depending of many pages,

so, the home page has a transparent background and the other pages could have a fill color or the same transparent color

```
  handleHeaderClass() {
    const currentPath = /other-page\/[0-9]+/i;

    if (pathname.match(currentPath)) {
      this.setState({ isTransparent: false });
    }
    //...
  }
```

I've been adding the class by adding a function to match the pathname with the current path from the location prop, but I realized that there will be many pages and nested pages that could have or not, the className to change the header

So i don't think that adding a condition for each pages would be a good way solution, so Im thinking to handle this by creating an action (using redux btw) to pass the className as a payload where is needed and the connected header receive this to change the color, but I don't know if is too much only to add a className, does reach router handle this through the route component?